# error al registrar datos e imagen con php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un formulario en donde se selecciona una imagen y se registra la ruta en la base de datos y se carga la imagen en una carpeta que se llama categorias, pero no quiere registrar la ruta de la imagen ni tampoco subir la imagen a la carpeta de categorias.

El código es el siguiente:

index.php

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2><font color="#000000"><b>Agregar Nuevo Producto</b></font></h2>
<form action="nuevo_prod2.php" method="POST" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">

<table border="0">
<tr>
        <td><label>Categría: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="categoria_sti" name="categoria_sti"></td>
</tr>
<tr>        
        <td><label>Nombre: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="nombre_sti" name="nombre_sti" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>        
        <td><label>Precio: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="preciboom" name="preciboom" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>        
        <td><label>Destacado: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="destacado" name="destacado" ></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
        <td><label>Diseño</label></td>
        <td><input name="patternim" type="file" id="patternim" class="checkout_input" required="required"></td>
</tr>   
</table>        
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
     </form>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Archivo que procesa los datos: nuevo_prod2.php

```
<?php
  include "conexion.php";
?>
<?php


    NuevoProducto($_POST['categoria_sti'], $_POST['nombre_sti'], $_POST['preciboom'], $_POST['destacado'], $_POST['patternim']);

    $nom=$_REQUEST["txtnom"];
    $patternim=$_FILES["patternim"]["name"];
    $ruta=$_FILES["patternim"]["tmp_name"];
    $destino="categorias/".$patternim;
    copy($ruta,$destino);


    function NuevoProducto($categoria_sti, $nombre_sti, $preciboom, $destacado, $patternim)
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $sentencia= "INSERT INTO stickerb (categoria_sti, nombre_sti, preciboom, destacado, patternim) VALUES ('".$categoria_sti."', '".$nombre_sti."', '".$preciboom."', '".$destacado."', '".$destino."') ";
        $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al ingresar los datos".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Producto Ingresado Exitosamante!!");
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

archivo de conexion.php

```
<?php
    $conexion= new mysqli("localhost", "root", "boom23140", "sticker1_boom");
    //Comprobar conexion
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        printf("Fallo la conexion");
    }
    else {
        //printf("Estas conectado");
    }
?>
```

Cuando lleno el formulario y presiono el boton guardar me sale en mensaje de que toda la información se guardo correctamente, pero el campo patternim que es en donde debería guardar la ruta queda en blanco, de que forma podría arreglar mi código para que funcione bien.

Muchas gracias cualquier ayuda sera de gran utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

En tu formulario si quieres subir una imagen a tu servidor debes incluir `enctype="multipart/form-data"`a la etiqueta.